# Changing the Source of an Image During a StoryBoard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I am attempting to have multiple images on my home page (around 30) that fade in and fade out by using a `StoryBoard`. At the moment I have the animation working perfectly on one picture, it looks like this;

```
private void OnDashboardPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
    TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);

    // Create a DoubleAnimation to fade the not selected option control
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();

    animation.From = 0.0;
    animation.To = 1.0;
    animation.Duration = new Duration(duration);

    // Configure the animation to target de property Opacity
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, testImage.Name);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

    // Add the animation to the storyboard
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

    storyboard.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
    animation.AutoReverse = true;

    // Begin the storyboard
    storyboard.Begin(this);
}
```

And my XAML;

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="http://www.online-image-editor.com/styles/2013/images/example_image.png" x:Name="testImage" Stretch="Uniform" />
</Grid>
```

As you can see I have a static source set here, but ultimately what I would like to do is to load all the images in a directory and change the source at the end of each animation so that a new image is displayed every time (until all 30 have been displayed), how can I do this?

EDIT: On completion of the storyboard;

```
storyboard.Completed += new EventHandler(Story_Completed); // In OnDashboardPageLoaded method

private void Story_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    storyboard.Begin(this);
}
```

Comment: *"change the source at the end of each animation"* - sounds like you don't want `RepeatBehavior.Forever` anymore. Rather start single animation/storyboard and [when it's finished](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7333462/1997232) do something and start another. `AutoReverse` can be easily achieved by exchanging `From` and `To`.

Comment: Do you want to blend an image over the previous one, or just fade out the current one, then change the source and fade in the next one?

Comment: @Clemens the latter Clemens, one fades out completely, source changes and the new one loads in. I have added a method in that just starts the storyboard again after it has completed, however it doesn't work... I've updated my code in the question

Answer (score 2):

The following method fades out an Image control, changes its `Source` property, and fades it in again. You can call it cyclically (e.g. controlled by a DispatcherTimer) with another ImageSource argument.

```
public static void ShowNextImage(Image image, ImageSource source, TimeSpan fadeTime)
{
    if (image.Source == null) // no fade out
    {
        image.Source = source;
        image.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty,
            new DoubleAnimation(0d, 1d, fadeTime));
    }
    else
    {
        var fadeOut = new DoubleAnimation(0d, fadeTime);

        fadeOut.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            image.Source = source;
            image.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty,
                new DoubleAnimation(1d, fadeTime));
        };

        image.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, fadeOut);
    }
}
```